# I need a script to automaticaly send email when a specific cell of google spreasheet turns to "Check Calibration Table"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet and I need to automatically send an email when a specific cell turns into "Check Calibration Table".

I've already tried this code, but it worked with all cells and not with the specific one that I need:

```
function CheckCalibrationeFE() {
    // Fetch Calibration and FE
    var CalibrationRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Painel de Controle").getRange("X15");
    // Check Calibration and FE
    if (CalibrationRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Painel de Controle").getRange("AF15")) {
        // Fetch the email address
        var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Detalhes do Projeto").getRange("B52");
        var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
        // Send Alert Email.
        var message = 'Cuidado'; // Second column
        var subject = 'Checar';
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably want to use a [time driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) for this since there is no trigger that does such a thing directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've got it set to run "on change."

Change your = in the if statement to === or to ==. The === will make sure the value and type match. == will just loosely match things (22 will == '22')

Also make sure you're getting the value of the cells in the range otherwise they'll return range (which is a match). You can check this by logging the variables to the G script console using Logger.log(foo).

```
function CheckCalibrationeFE() {
    // Fetch Calibration and FE
    var CalibrationRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Painel de Controle").getRange("X15").getValue();
    // Check Calibration and FE
    if (CalibrationRange === SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Painel de Controle").getRange("AF15").getValue()) {
        // Fetch the email address
        var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Detalhes do Projeto").getRange("B52");
        var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
        // Send Alert Email.
        var message = 'Cuidado'; // Second column
        var subject = 'Checar';
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```